# How to Run a jQuery Script after a Javascript Script has Finished in WordPress

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I've got javascript (a) and jQuery script (b). I need (b) to run after (a) has finished running. I need them to run sequentially. How do I do that?

In wp_enqueue_script, I've made (b) dependent on (a), but it appears that (b) runs before (a) has finished processing.

I'm trying to use the_maps_bounds, a variable I've put in the global scope. It gets set in (a) and used in (b). The problem is that (b) is trying to use the variable before it has been set.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to post the code for (a) so we can see how/when/where is the variable set

Comment: FYI: jQuery IS javascript. One and the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this, wrap wp_enqueue_script in a function and run it through the action hook wp_enqueue_scripts while using the 'priority' parameter available in [add_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) to set the load order.

```
function these_go_first() {
    wp_enqueue_script('first_script', '[path to file]/first.js', array('jquery'), '1.0' );
}
function these_go_first() {
    wp_enqueue_script('after_script', '[path to file]/after.js', array('jquery', 'first_script'), '1.0' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'these_go_first', 1);
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'these_go_after', 2);
```

wp_enqueue_script can also define script [dependencies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Parameters) as well. This is why I added 'first_script' which I had already defined in the function just before, to the dependencies array in the second function.

Comment: I doubt that this is the issue here. He is probably setting that variable after an ajax event or something...

Comment: hmmm... well running the scripts in the correct order using this could help.

Comment: Hi @DrewGourley Thank you for the help. It was a timing problem. My function was firing before the map fully loaded. I added your code, and the timing was still off. So in addition, I added an eventListener. It works now. Thank you.